# How YouTube "stats for nerds" work. Or how to get the codec information of a video being played from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video

YouTube stats for nerds will show the codec of the video being played.

How to get the same data from JavaScript. Is there a generic API in mediasource or html video element to get the data.

Comment: I meant a generic API to the browser. And not a YouTube API to get the codec data.

Comment: For example: the dropped frames shown in "stats for nerds" can be queried using <Html video element>.webkitDroppedFrameCount or <Html video element>.getVideoPlaybaclQ

Comment: Sorry getVideoPlaybackQuality()

Answer (score 0):

HTML video tag standard do not have codec information, YouTube stats for nerds is implemented by themselves and get these video information from their back end server.
You can find what you can get by looking Properties in [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) and [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement)

BTW, Youtube is using DASH and MSE nowadays, you may get the codec by parsing DASH mpd file if these data was presented there.